# IIS Express will not pick up changes to _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, razor, iis-express

We've got a web developer working on content changes to an existing site.  He's doing this in a VM on his Mac, and changes to the _Layout.cshtml file are not reflected when refreshing the browser.  Changes to other files (such as CSS or images) are reflected immediately, so it doesn't appear to be a browser caching issue.  Doesn't seem to matter whether changes are made in VS.NET or an external editor.

The setup is Windows 7 32-bit VM, IIS Express serving via applicationhost.config file for several different projects that combine into a single site.

It works on several other dev machines (they're not VMs)

Bouncing IIS Express makes the change show up. We've tried deleting Temporary ASP.NET Files, etc., no difference.

What do?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the exact same problem. It's an issue with vmware and mapping. If windows and vmware are sharing the same folders, the only way to get IIS express to recognize your changes is to stop and restart the server. If you move your project into the windows installation drive, C: as an example, you will see that the problem disappears. Crazy stuff and trying to look for a better solution.

Thanks

Tyrone

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Was editing files from Mac and running IIS in VM. Usually I keep Visual Studio opened. Closing VS fixed the issue. IIS is picking up changes to the views straight away.

Comment: I had the same issue using Visual Studio on natively on a windows machine. Closing and opening VS fixed the issue for me as well